# count duplicate values in array using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with 5 questions and 3 different answers for each question.

e.g. 
q1. whats is your favorite color?

radio button-1. value blue
radio button-2. value red
radio button-3. value grey

most of these questions have the same value (blue, red, grey), which is what I want, however, I'm trying to add all the values together at the end of the form so I can determine if the person filling out the form equals one of the values (blue, red, or grey).

I'm building this form with angularjs and this is what i have so far.

```
 <label>Q1. what is your favorite color?</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
          <input type="radio" ng-model="formData.color" value="blue">
              blue
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
           <input type="radio" ng-model="formData.color" value="red">
                red
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
          <input type="radio" ng-model="formData.color" value="grey">
               grey
            </label>
        </div>
```

this bit of code only works if I have the values already entered into the variable

```
$scope.formData = { };
$scope.formData = [];
$scope.formData.sort();
var current = null;
var cnt = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.formData.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.formData[i] != current) {
        if (cnt > 0) {
            console.log(current + ' shows ' + cnt + ' times');
        }
        current = $scope.formData[i];
        cnt = 1;
    } else {
        cnt++;
    }
}
if (cnt > 0) {
   console.log(current + ' shows ' + cnt + ' times');
}
```

Comment: based on your `ng-model` ... `formdata` is an object with one property `color`. Objects aren't sortable so your controller code is a bit confusing. Can you create a demo with a couple of questions so we can see your code context more

Comment: the results page would show the color that best represents that person based on the answers selected.  does that makes sense? I'm prolly doing it wrong...
http://plnkr.co/edit/FtL8arjcHPUEbs4r1BJS

Comment: handy trick to make data readable using angular `json` filter ..`{{ formData |json }}`

Comment: so can see that you have an object in your data print. Since not array it has no length. Can loop over properties though and create another object that has colors as keys and counts as value. See if this helps  http://jsfiddle.net/8eq0mnbL/

Comment: would this help http://plnkr.co/edit/SXJaFH0EfbClLuyHI7vY?p=preview ?

Comment: thats it klode!
thanks!

Comment: klode: for each question thats being repeated in the ng-repeat, can I change the label name(s) so that they're not all the same but keep the value the same?

Comment: Glad it helped. What do you mean by "label name"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example solution [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SXJaFH0EfbClLuyHI7vY?p=preview). Would it work?

**controller**

```
  $scope.questions = [
    'Q1. what is your favorite color?',
    'Q2. what color is your car?',
    'Q3. what color best represents you?'
  ];
  $scope.formData = [];

  $scope.stats = function() {
    $scope.results = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.formData.length; i++) {
      var color = $scope.formData[i];
      if(color) {
        if ($scope.results.hasOwnProperty(color)) {
          $scope.results[color]++;
        } else {
          $scope.results[color] = 1;
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

**template**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="q in questions">
  <label>{{q}}</label>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="formData[$index]" value="blue">blue
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="formData[$index]" value="red">red
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="formData[$index]" value="grey">grey
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<button ng-click="stats()">show results</button>

<ul>
<li ng-repeat="(c, n) in results"> {{c}} shows {{n}} times</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So instead of repeating the radio labels "blue, red, grey" for each question in the ng-repeat, I would need to have different answers for each question, while still keep the values the same.

Comment: one approach can be to start thinking what is the data structure for your answers. For example [{value11: label11, value12: label12, ....}, {value21: label21, value22: label22,...} ...] and next figure out how to code them in your controllers and templates

Comment: answers[1] = {value11: label11, value12: label12, ....}; answers[2]={value21: label21, value22: label22,...}

Comment: @Society43 could you vote/accept the answer if you find it useful?